# how to implement invert selection for checkbox in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to inverse selection for checkbox in WPF?
Eg: if there are 3 checkbox A, B, C and checkbox A and C are checked while B is unchecked. 
[Image1: Before clicking on the inverse button, A and C are checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkH1Q.png)
If I click on the button for inverse selection, then A and C should be unchecked and B should be checked as shown in image2

[image2: After clicking on inverse button, B is checked and A , C are unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0I5k.png)

[Example for inverse selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDOEG.png)

Comment: When following the MVVM pattern this is easy to achieve in the viewmodel. What have you tryed and where do you struggle?

Comment: are you using MVVM or programming in your code-behind?

Comment: I am not using MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
With your added information that you want to create the checkboxes dynamically i recommend you use this XAML Code:

```
        <StackPanel Name="stk">                
            <!-- Add checkboxes dynamically to this stackpanel -->
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Invert</Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

And this Click event

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var cb in stk.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            cb.IsChecked = !cb.IsChecked;
        }
    }
```

use this to add checkboxes:

```
stk.Children.Add(new CheckBox());
```

Comment: checkbox are dynamically loaded. I dont know how many checkbox will be there

Comment: Edited my answer to work with a dynamic amount of checkboxes

Answer (score -1):

```
 <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Name="CB1" Content="A" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Name="CB2" Content="B"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Name="CB3" Content="C" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
    <Button Name="btnInvert" Content="Invert" Click="btnInvert_Click" ></Button>
 </StackPanel>
```

Code logic:

```
 private void btnInvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CB1.IsChecked == true && CB3.IsChecked == true)
        {
            CB2.IsChecked = true;
            CB1.IsChecked = false;
            CB3.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CB2.IsChecked = false;
            CB1.IsChecked = true;
            CB3.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
```

Or Simply:

```
 private void btnInvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CB1.IsChecked == true && CB3.IsChecked == true)
        {
            CB2.IsChecked = true;
            CB1.IsChecked = false;
            CB3.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
```

Based on your requirement.

```
if (CB1.IsChecked == true && CB3.IsChecked == true&& CB2.IsChecked== false)
        {
            CB2.IsChecked = true;
            CB1.IsChecked = false;
            CB3.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CB2.IsChecked = false;
            CB1.IsChecked = true;
            CB3.IsChecked = true;
        }
```

Comment: you can use `CB2.IsChecked = !CB2.IsChecked` that will invert the value as well with a lot less code but he wants to use it with a dynamic amount of checkboxes

Comment: Yeah,Of course we can use dynamically, but by doing statically here we are able to implement the logic, if A and C are checked then irrespective of B is checked or unchecked ,it ll check the B and uncheck A and B. and if any of A or C or both are unchecked ,then it ll check both A and C ,uncheck B.

Comment: he want to flip the selection independant of the current stat not only if the exact logic he describes is matched